# Merge Video drivers for graphics application in Turbo C++

Tags: turbo-c++

How to merge Video drivers for graphics application in Turbo C++?

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to Turbo C++ / DOS Borland Graphics Interface (BGI) and those VGA driver files?

You need to create a DOS overlay...